# How to divide a border into 4 equal parts?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a rectangle:

```
<div id="rec">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rec {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/tquq01hq/

I want to do divide the border to 4 equal parts and each part will be in a different color. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide the border-color values `border-color: red green blue grey;`

```
#rec {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: red green blue grey;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/24rn5zcr/)**

Comment: Oh, pretty easy. Thanks

Comment: yup same for circle. try adding border-radius n test.

Comment: I'll, but I can do it just more 7 minutes. @GustvandeWal

Comment: @WebR it's worth noting as well that you can access all the properties for each side individually e.g. `border-left: dashed 2px yellow;`